# how to combine multi bash parameter expansion

Tags: bash, parameters, expansion

bash parameter expansion has a few useful function, e.g. substring ,replace,upper,lower. how to combine these function without define temporary parameter?

```
f="abc.txt"
e=${f:4:3}   #txt
echo ${e^^}  #TXT
```

I define e to upper the txt. echo ${${f:4:3}^^} can not work. Is it  possible omit e. if in java i can write

```
String f="abc.txt";
System.out.print(f.substring(4,7).toUpperCase());
```

even, i can

```
System.out.print("abc.txt".substring(4,7).toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Bash, unlike Java, is not designed as an application language, it is a *shell*.  You can't expect the same level of functionality in both, they are different tools for different jobs.  Specifically for this case, shell parsing is done in a completely different way to conventional programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible in `bash` AFAIK.

To make it possible we would need some sort of prioritization (along-with parsing logic changes) when more than 1 parameter expansion is specified, for which there is no code as of now.